# Query junction table-many to many relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to run a query for a many-many relationship, I created a junction table to do that. Now I'm having issues getting no results when I'm expecting to return 3 rows for each of indexes 122,123,124, can anyone point out my errors, thank you

```
SELECT  *  FROM [Moldingdata].[dbo].[mach_part_junction] ORDER BY [machinename] ASC

SELECT  MachineList.machinename ,JDEPARTIMGLU.Jde_part_num
 from mach_part_junction 
 INNER JOIN MachineList on mach_part_junction.machinename = machinelist.Machine_ID
 INNER JOIN JDEPARTIMGLU on mach_part_junction.machinename = machinelist.Machine_ID
 WHERE mach_part_junction.machinename= 'MM01'
```

Results:

```
machinename ndx_jde_part_img
----------- ----------------
MM01        122
MM01        123
MM01        124
MM04        122
MM15        124
MM17        122
MM32        122
MM32        123

(8 row(s) affected)


machinename Jde_part_num
----------- --------------------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I troubleshoot queries like this I generally do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mach_part_junction
INNER JOIN MachineList on mach_part_junction.machinename = machinelist.Machine_ID
```

Then I add the next JOIN:

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM mach_part_junction
    INNER JOIN MachineList on mach_part_junction.machinename = machinelist.Machine_ID
INNER JOIN JDEPARTIMGLU on mach_part_junction.machinename = machinelist.Machine_ID
```

then the WHERE (if the tables aren't too big)

That way you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The join conditions on your second and third table are the same.

It looks like the third table's join condition is the one that needs to be changed.